# Changing box background-color to the equal hex taken from database

Tags: javascript, css, database, ruby-on-rails-3, styling

I store labels/tags in my database (mockup below):

```
labels:
  text:string //name of the label/tag
  color:string //hex color of the tag (with '#' at the beggining)
```

And I have articles, which are connected with this labels. I want to show in my list of articles its tags, but as a colour rectangle (written in css as a block with background-color) - but how set a specified color from database to each box background-color style? I read about some js functions that are changing site background after :click or :hover but still I don't really know (I barely know js) how to implement it in my app :/ please help!

At the moment I'm just displaying box with the text in it (name of the tag):

```
- a.labels.each do |l|
  .article_tags
    = l.text
```

'Article_tags' class is that box, which should change its background to the color taken from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- a.labels.each do |l|
  .article_tags{:style => "background-color:#{l.color}"}
    = l.text
```

Comment: no way! IT WORKS! thank You, I didn't think about this way to resolve this problem :D